# Using python Multiprocessing Pool for accessing split files, search bytestream and then concat the values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to multiprocessing.I've a large binary files, which I've split. I'm going to search specific values(here 1002 and 1376)  in file, collect their count in dictionary and return total count. But I am not finding correct way to do it. Below definition of f1 doesn't seem to be right. what I want is one process will use all 3 parameters of one tuple as a parameters of f1 and another process will use another tuple. return me count of each number in dictionary. so each process may return {1002:40,1376:33} and {1002:24,1376:65}

```
def f1(file_name, num1, num2):
      Vdict=defaultdict(list)    
      with open (file_name,'rb') as f:
          b=f.read(188)
          while len(b)>0:
              ...
              compare if b has 1002 or 1376 then add Vdict[1002]=Vdict[1002]+1 or 
              Vdict[1376]=Vdict[1376]+1
      return Vdict 
 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = Pool()
    numbers = [('file_1.ts',1002,1376), ('file_2.ts',1002,1376)]
    result2=pool.starmap(f1,numbers )
    print(result2)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print('done!')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a common data structure (see `result`)

```
import multiprocessing


def worker(procnum, return_dict):
    """worker function"""
    print(str(procnum) + " sharing-state!")
    return_dict[procnum] = procnum


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # see https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    result = manager.dict()
    jobs = []
    for i in range(3):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(i, result))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()

    for proc in jobs:
        proc.join()
    print(result.values())
```

Comment: I did not understand the the value 'i' you passed in args=(i, result),  each tuple (file, number1, number2) should be used by each processes running at a same time, and both these processes returns the count of number1 and number2 in dictionary which I can capture in main and combine.    Is it what your sample code will do?

Comment: Try to run the sample. After that,see how you can adopt it to our needs. I think it can work for you.

Comment: I ran, by creating two different process manually (dictionary and list both are separate and then collected them.  problem is   [1]  I don't see it has improved as expected. if 10 min video is split to two 5 min video, I expect completion in < 10 min. But it is always > 15 mins  [2] when I ran with single dictionary the count always came different each time I run.

Comment: with Manager() as manager:
        d = manager.dict()
        d1= manager.dict()
       l=manager.list(['file_1.ts',1002,1376])
        l2=manager.list(['file_2.ts',1002,1376])
 p = Process(target=get_PTS, args=(d, l))
        p.start()
        p2 = Process(target=get_PTS, args=(d1, l2))
        p2.start()